# Adjuntar csv al enviar email en Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

Necesito adjuntar un csv y enviarlo por email, lo que intente son los siguientes casos si exito:

Genero el csv y lo paso al mail para adjuntarlo:

```
      $csv = Excel::raw($this->collection(), BaseExcel::CSV);

      Mail::send(new LeadSubmittedEmail($lead, $csv));
```

y al momento de enviarlo hago:

```
  return $this->from($this->listingNoReply)
        ->attachData($this->csv, 'file.csv')
        ->to($this->leadRecipients)
        ->view('emails.withSellerLead.leadSubmitted');
```

Esto envía el email pero con el archivo adjunto vacío

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes chequear que efectivamente la variable `$csv` contiene texto o esta vacia?

Comment: Ademas, incluye el *mime-type* de archivos CSV en el adjunto para ayudar a reconocer el tipo de archivo `->attachData($this->csv, 'file.csv', 'text/csv')`

Comment: @F.Igor efectivamente esta vacío la variable $csv, pero si cambio por BaseExcel::XLSX ahi si me genera como si fuera el file_get_content y envia el mail adjunto pero se ve todo feo, no entiendo porque no funciona el CSV